# Замена значений датафрейма в соответствии с заданным значением

Tags: python

Хочу заменить значения во всех столбцах датафрейма таким образом, что если они совпадают со значением в нулевой строке, то ставь 1, если не совпадают- ставь 0. Короче, обработчик правильности ответа.
Но сталкиваюсь с тем, что replace учитывает регистр букв, а если я пытаюсь весь df привести к нижнему регистру, он не перезаписывается.

| Тексты_1 | Тексты_2 | Тексты_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| БАВГ | БГВДА | ВБДГА |
| ДАВГБ | NA | ВБДГА |
| NA | бвгад | вбдга |
| дбгав | бгвда | NA |
| NA | бвгда | NA |
| NA | БВГДА | NA |
| дбавг | NA | NA |
| ДБАВГ | БГВДА | ВБДАГ |
| NA | БАВГД | NA |
| NA | Бвгда | Вбдга |

```
df.columns = [x.lower() for x in df.columns]
for col in df.columns:
    df[col][1:].replace(df[col][0], 1)
```

Можно ли это как-нибудь обойти?
Исходные данные на Листе 1, Желаемый результат на Листе 2

[Ссылка](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dkQ105BN4-NpR3bBKLiZ8J8TfGfys7Wh68BfajDWqp0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно как-нибудь так:

```
res = df.applymap(lambda x:x.lower() if type(x) == str else x)
res[res==res.iloc[0]]=1
res[res.notna()&res.ne(1)]=0
res.loc[0] = df.loc[0]
```

Тогда res будет:

```
  Тексты_1 Тексты_2 Тексты_3
0    ДБАВГ    БГВДА    ВБДГА
1        0      NaN        1
2      NaN        0        1
3        0        1      NaN
4      NaN        0      NaN
5      NaN        0      NaN
6        1      NaN      NaN
7        1        1        0
8      NaN        0      NaN
9      NaN        0        1
```

Для красоты можно еще сделать:

```
res=res.fillna("")
```

тогда res будет:

```
  Тексты_1 Тексты_2 Тексты_3
0    ДБАВГ    БГВДА    ВБДГА
1        0                 1
2                 0        1
3        0        1         
4                 0         
5                 0         
6        1                  
7        1        1        0
8                 0         
9                 0        1
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Изучу, буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    1:["ds", "sdads", "DS", "sdasd,"],
    2: ["a", "dsad", "saa", "a"]
})

    1   2
0   ds  a
1   sdads   dsad
2   DS  saa
3   sdasd,  a

df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
df[1] = (df[1] == "ds").astype(int)
df[2] = (df[2] == "a").astype(int)
df

    1   2
0   1   1
1   0   0
2   1   0
3   0   1
```